# I used Youtube Data API v3 to get live broadcast, as it was working fine yesterday but today is gives this error

Tags: php, api, youtube

```
A service error occurred: { "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "authError", "message": "Invalid Credentials", "locationType": "header", "location": "Authorization" } ], "code": 401, "message": "Invalid Credentials" } }
```

**(it was in php)**

**My credentials are still same and not expired.**

```
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/insert#try-it
```

P.S: I cannot upload the whole code here.

Comment: Contact YouTube support.